# Get values from a dataframe into a series of web API requests

Tags: python, pandas, rest, dataframe

I'm very very new to Python (please be kind) and so I don't think in a Python way... yet.

I need to build a series of 16 web API strings to get weather data for a specific location from a websource and then post each one to a new location in knack. I am using a pandas dataframe to hold the hardcoded locations data and I want to itterate through each one to get/post the correct data.

```
import requests, json, pytemperature
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from datetime import date

#Important information for each weather station
stations = pd.DataFrame([
                    ['EGPD', 'Aberdeen','1099','-2.1981','57.2025'],
                    ['EGUC', 'Aberporth','1109','-4.5594','52.1147'],
                    ['EGAA', 'Belfast','1094','-6.2158','54.6575'],
                    ['EGBB', 'Birmingham','1093','-1.7481','52.4539'],
                    ['EGQM', 'Boulmer','1095','-1.6033','55.4219'],
                    ['EGHH', 'Bournemouth','1104','-1.8425','50.7800'],
                    ['EGGD', 'Bristol','1102','-2.7192','51.3828'],
                    ['EGKK', 'Gatwick','1103','-0.1903','51.1481'],
                    ['EGPF', 'Glasgow','1106','-4.4331','55.8719'],
                    ['EGLL', 'Leeming','1100','-1.5356','54.2925'],
                    ['EGQL', 'Leuchars','1098','-2.8686','56.3731'],
                    ['EGCC', 'Manchester','1105','-2.2750','53.3539'],
                    ['EGDB', 'Plymouth','1108','-4.1058','50.4228'],
                    ['EGPO', 'Stornoway','1101','-6.3311','58.2156'],
                    ['EGXW', 'Waddington','1097','-0.5308','53.1725'],
                    ['EGUW', 'Wattisham','1096','0.9558','52.1269']
                   ],
                   index=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'],
                   columns=['Station', 'Name', 'Code', 'Lon', 'Lat'])

#Basic Information for the API request
URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
AUTH = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

#HOW TO USE THE LAT AND LON FROM THE STATIONS DATAFRAME ?
LAT = "51.1481"
LON = "-0.1903"

#Build the GET query
response = requests.get(URL+"lon="+LON+"&lat="+LAT+"&appid="+AUTH)
data = response.json()

#Flatten the data
data_df = json_normalize(data,sep="_")

#Choose the specific column(s) to post 
MyStationID = stations.iloc[0]['Station'] #Field_1382
MyStation = data_df.iloc[0]['name'] #Field_1383
MyCoords = stations.iloc[0]['Lon'],stations.iloc[0]['Lat'] #Field_1384
MySLCode = stations.iloc[0]['Code'] #Field_1381
MyDate = date.today() #Field_1386
MyTemp = pytemperature.k2c(data_df.iloc[0]['main_temp_min']) #Field_1389
MyMinTemp = pytemperature.k2c(data_df.iloc[0]['main_temp_min']) #Field_1387
MyMaxTemp = pytemperature.k2c(data_df.iloc[0]['main_temp_max']) #Field_1388

#Build the POST query
knackURL = "https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_96/records"
payload = '{ \
            "field_1386": "' + str(MyDate) + '", \
            "field_1382": "' + str(MyStationID) + '", \
            "field_1383": "' + str(MyStation) + '", \
            "field_1381": "' + str(MySLCode) + '", \
            "field_1384": "' + str(MyCoords) + '", \
            "field_1389": "' + str(MyTemp) + '", \
            "field_1387": "' + str(MyMinTemp) + '", \
            "field_1388": "' + str(MyMaxTemp) + '" \
           }'

knackHEADERS = {
    'X-Knack-Application-Id': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'X-Knack-REST-API-Key': "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", knackURL, data=payload, headers=knackHEADERS)
print(response.text)
```

Hopefully it makes sense what I am trying to do, however I know that I'm not thinking python enough. What makes sense to me is to loop through each row in the stations dataframe and use the variables to complete the get API URL and use in the post payload.

I welcome any advice or suggestions.

Comment: I'd say it's a good approach, but could be improved.  Questions like, is a dataframe really necessary here to store request parameters should be addressed later.  If they're hard coded in, like you have them, the overhead of constructing a df to store them isnt needed.  The biggest bottleneck will be in waiting on all of the responses from each request.  If you want to be more performant, look into asynchronous I/O especially if the number of requests goes up on your end.  Also, think about the output, is pandas needed for the final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `zip` maybe?

```py
for lon, lat in zip(df['Lon'], df['Lat']):
    response = requests.get(URL+"lon="+lon+"&lat="+lat+"&appid="+AUTH)
    data = response.json()
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you this looks really promising !